# Tensorflow batch: keep result as strings

Tags: python, tensorflow

This simple program

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = 'string'
batch = tf.train.batch([tf.constant(input)], batch_size=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners()
    output, = sess.run(batch)

    print(1, input, output)
    print(2, str(output, 'utf-8'))
    print(3, input.split('i'))
    print(4, str(output, 'utf-8').split('i'))
    print(5, output.split('i'))
```

prints

> 1 string b'string'
>   2 string
>   3 ['str', 'ng']
>   4 ['str', 'ng']
>   ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Session has been closed.
>         print(5, output.split('i'))
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Why isn't the result a list of strings, if the input is?

*OK, @jdehesa [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278261/tensorflow-batch-keep-result-as-strings/53279982?noredirect=1#comment93444348_53279982) **WHY**, but not how to 'fix' it.* I can apply **bytes.decode()** to the results of session:

```
output, = map(bytes.decode, sess.run(batch))
```

And there exists **tf.map_fn()** that should do the same on tensors. The only question is how I can use this in my scenario?

---

*PS*: actually, the error message is puzzling, too. The problem is that we provide a bytes object, not a string. But the **TypeError** suggests exactly the opposite.

*PPS*: the error message explained, thanks to @jdehesa: it was about the *split()*'s parameter, not the object. `output.split(b'i')` works well!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question/problem. The result is a list of strings, just of length one in this case, due to the definition of `batch`. Make it `batch_size=2` and you will have `[b'string' b'string']` as output, etc.

Comment: @Uvar, I have clarified my question

Comment: It looks like, **session.py** has a class `_ElementFetchMapper` which has `_contraction_fn` - a function that is responsible, also, for converting the results to expected types. But `_REGISTERED_EXPANSIONS` is a constant in *tensorflow 1.12*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `output` is a `bytes` object, because TensorFlow `tf.string` tensors are indeed made of `bytes`. But then you are trying to use `split` with a `str` separator, and that is why it complains. Try:

```
output.split(b'i')
```

or:

```
output.decode().split('i')
```

Comment: Cool, `decode()` is nicer than str(..., 'utf-8'). But still, the question was: is there a way to get *decoded* strings from **run(batch)**?

Comment: @AlexCohn Ah, well, about that, I think not. `str` (Python 3 `str`, that is) is just not a supported type in TensorFlow. If you look "under the hood", `tf.string` is in C++ `tensorflow::string`, which is [currently defined as `std::string`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/core/platform/types.h#L42), i.e. something like `bytes`. I'm not 100% sure that it is not possible but I don't see where could TensorFlow get the decoded strings from (at least at C++ level, there could be something at Python level implemented for convenience but I haven't seen it).

Comment: I know I can write `map(bytes.decode, sess.run(batch))` but I would prefer for this to happen inside **run()**.

Comment: @AlexCohn Actually I'm seeing only now there is this function [`tf.compat.as_text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/as_text), which just calls `decode` if the object is `bytes`. Doesn't seem like they are planning to support it anytime soon... The problem is, some ops really should return bytes (e.g. reading a binary file), and I suppose wrapping some to return `str` but not others would be inconsistent and hard to maintain. Also it would fix the encoding to e.g. utf8 (unless you implemented options)... And at the same time you want consistent behavior across languages.

Comment: I guess there should be some way to apply **tf.map_fn()**, only I don't know how